# CREATE_FAILED for AWS::RDS::DBCluster with input not matching expected format error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a RDS DB cluster for postgres using cloudformation template.

I am getting this error which states: "Given input did not match expected format".

I am scratching my head and cannot figure out what's wrong with my cloudformation template.
Here's my template.

```
  MyDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        - !Sub "${AWS::Region}a"
        - !Sub "${AWS::Region}b"
        - !Sub "${AWS::Region}c"
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 7
      DatabaseName: "MyDB"
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-db-cluster
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: "default.aurora-postgresql13"
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      EngineVersion: '13.8'
      Port: 5432
      MasterUsername: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref MyDBMasterSecret, ':secretString:username}}']]
      MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{{resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref MyDBMasterSecret, ':secretString:password}}']]
      PreferredBackupWindow: '10:21-10:51'
      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: 'thu:03:03-thu:03:33'
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref MyDBSecurityGroup
      StorageEncrypted: true
      KmsKeyId: !Ref MyDBKmsKey
      EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication: false
      EngineMode: 'provisioned'
      DeletionProtection: true
      EnableHttpEndpoint: false
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: true
        MinCapacity: 2
        MaxCapacity: 8
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 900
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `SecretString` instead of `secretString `.

Comment: What is the FULL error message and full template?

Comment: @AndresBores This seems to have solved this problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution. When you use a [dynamic reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/cfn-example_reference-secret.html) to retrieve secrets from Secrets manager in CloudFormation, you must use this pattern:

```
{{resolve:secretsmanager:secret-id:SecretString:json-key:version-stage:version-id}}
```

You need to take into account that it is case sensitive. That's why changing `secureString` to `SecureString` resolved the issue.

Comment: Andres Bores Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes across this and you're using CDK.

Check that when you are creating a secret you don't accidentally use `SecretValue` directly and you're using a method (like `SecretValue.unsafe_plain_text()`).

In python your type checker won't pick up on it so it's easy to miss.